# Eigenvectors of the derivative operator are the exponential function

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, generalized-eigenvector

The eigenvectors of the derivative operator are the exponential function. The derivative operator is not Hermitian, so we get complex eigenvalues.

$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lambda f(x) \Rightarrow f(x)=Ce^{\lambda x}$

what is the solution of the eigenvalue problem: $e^{zcos(x)}$

$\frac{d}{dx} e^{zcosx} = -ze^{zcosx}sin(x)$

$-\frac{1}{sinx}\frac{d}{dx} e^{zcosx} = ze^{zcosx}$

seeking for the eigenvectors. I don't see the solution.

I am very lost. Thank you.

Comment: How is $e^{z\cos x}$ an operator?

Comment: Oh sorry I edited my question, for find the eigenvalue problem, I use derivative as operator. I couldn't find the soln. @JackyChong

Comment: If the derivative is your operator and you already know all the eigenfunctions are exponential $e^{\lambda x}$, then what does $e^{z\cos x}$ have to do with anything?